# Python Decision Tree Classifier batch_prob_classify function

Tags: python, nltk, decision-tree

I am trying to run the Decision tree code provided in this following nltk site 
http://www.nltk.org/howto/classify.html

```
>>> train = [
...      (dict(a=1,b=1,c=1), 'y'),
...      (dict(a=1,b=1,c=1), 'x'),
...      (dict(a=1,b=1,c=0), 'y'),
...      (dict(a=0,b=1,c=1), 'x'),
...      (dict(a=0,b=1,c=1), 'y'),
...      (dict(a=0,b=0,c=1), 'y'),
...      (dict(a=0,b=1,c=0), 'x'),
...      (dict(a=0,b=0,c=0), 'x'),
...      (dict(a=0,b=1,c=1), 'y'),
...      ]
>>>
>>>
>>> test = [
...      (dict(a=1,b=0,c=1)), # unseen
...      (dict(a=1,b=0,c=0)), # unseen
...      (dict(a=0,b=1,c=1)), # seen 3 times, labels=y,y,x
...      (dict(a=0,b=1,c=0)), # seen 1 time, label=x
...      ]
>>>
>>>
>>> import nltk
>>> classifier = nltk.classify.DecisionTreeClassifier.train(train, entropy_cutoff=0, support_cutoff=0)
>>> sorted(classifier.labels())
['x', 'y']
>>> print(classifier)
c=0? .................................................. x
  a=0? ................................................ x
  a=1? ................................................ y
c=1? .................................................. y

>>> classifier.batch_classify(test)
['y', 'y', 'y', 'x']
>>> for pdist in classifier.batch_prob_classify(test):
...      print('%.4f %.4f' % (pdist.prob('x'), pdist.prob('y')))
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/classify/api.py", line 87, in batch_prob_classify
    return [self.prob_classify(fs) for fs in featuresets]
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/classify/api.py", line 67, in prob_classify
    raise NotImplementedError()
NotImplementedError
>>>
```

The problem is issue with batch_prob_classify function. Can any one please suggest how to resolve the issue and how to get probability distribution values.

Answer (score 1):

The `DecisionTreeClassifier` uses the probability class `MLEProbDist`, which does not have any `prob` methods. The `NaiveBayesClassifier`, on the other hand, uses the probability class `ELEProbDist`, which in turn inherits from the `LidstoneProbDist` probability class and **does** provide a `prob` method.

So unless you want to create a subclass of `DecisionTreeClassifier` and add in the `prob` method yourself, you might want to use the `NaiveBayesClassifier` instead:

```
>>> classifier = nltk.classify.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train)  # note the use of NaiveBayesClassifier here
>>> for pdist in classifier.batch_prob_classify(test):
      print('%.4f %.4f' % (pdist.prob('x'), pdist.prob('y')))


0.3104 0.6896
0.5746 0.4254
0.3685 0.6315
0.6365 0.3635
```

As @Mike points out, you received the expected result. You may have become confused by a very similar example earlier in the page.

Comment: How I can add a prob method from DecisionTreeClassifier ? Can you provide any example or tutorial please ?

Comment: Do I have to add the method in the python package decision tree module or totally separate class. Thanks.

Comment: @Raid That would take a fair bit of work, and I don't have time to write that now. You would prob subclass the class `DecisionTreeClassifier` like this: `DecisionTreeClassifier2(nltk.classify.DecisionTreeClassifier): . . .`. Then you would use your typical Python subclassing strategies to add in the `feature_probdist` and `label_probdist`. You will probably need to overwrite [the `train` method here](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/decisiontree.html) with a method that also includes the functionality of [this train method](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/naivebayes.html).